# sort custom post type by display name

Tags: custom-post-types, sort

I am trying to sort my custom post type in a few different ways using a dropdown.

When I try to sort it as the display_name it doesn't work.

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('orderby' => 'display_name') );
```

It works well on a few other sort ways like 'title' 'comment_count' but when I want to sort from the authors real name and not username it doesn't work anymore. 
Any hint how this can be fixed?

Comment: I fixed this issue by adding a new post_meta to my custom_post_type... which added both 

    add_post_meta($post->ID, 'mlp_author', $current_user->first_name . $current_user->last_name);

Then sorting by that post_meta using:
    
    array('meta_key' => 'mlp_author', 'orderby => 'meta_value')

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and "accept" it.

Comment: Have you seen this question: [Sort custom post type list table by display name of a user id stored as post meta value](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/58638/73)

Comment: s_ha_dum - I will do that now, but I couldn't do it yesterday because I've to few points.
toscho - I think I went through that yesterday when I were searching for an answer but I thought there could be an easier way to fix it. Atleast that wasn't exactly the same way I wanted to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding a new post_meta to my custom_post_type... which added both

```
add_post_meta($postid$current_user->first_name . $current_user->last_name;
```

Then sorting by that post_meta using:

```
array('meta_key' => 'mlp_author', 'orderby => 'meta_value')
```